# nested loop in C does not work

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, nested

I am trying make this nested loop work.. for some reason the code does not go into the second loop..it keeps asking for a letter to enter so it does not go into the code with the k counter... and ask me 10 times to enter a letter

thanks.

```
 char letter;
 int proposition;
 int i,k;
 char dashes[50];
 proposition=10;
 for (i=0;i<proposition;i++){
    printf("enter letter to guess %s\n");
    scanf("%s", &letter);
     for(k=0;k<ret;k++){
        if (tab[k] == letter){
            dashes[k]= letter;
            printf("%s\n", dashes);
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where do you define `ret` used in the inner loop's comparison?

Comment: What is the value of ret in k<ret ?

Comment: the ret is initialized to the lenght of a string. that i have previously enter. and use the following function to get the lenght.
`int string_lenght(char t[]){
    int j;
    j=0;
    while (t[j] != '\0'){
    j++;
}
    return j;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
char letter[2];
int proposition;
int i,k;
char dashes[50]={0};
memset(dashes, '-', strlen(tab));
proposition=10;
for (i=0;i<proposition;i++){
   printf("enter letter to guess %%s\n");
   scanf("%1s", letter);
    for(k=0;k<ret;k++){
       if (tab[k] == *letter){
           dashes[k]= *letter;
           printf("%s\n", dashes);
       }
   }
 }
```

---

may be sample

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char *tab = "foobar";
    int ret = strlen(tab);
    char letter[2];
    int proposition;
    int i,k, match=0;
    char dashes[50]={0};
    memset(dashes, '-', ret);
    proposition=10;
    for (i=0;i<proposition;i++){
        if(match == ret)
            break;
        printf("enter letter to guess\n");
        scanf("%s", letter);
        for(k=0;k<ret;k++){
            if (tab[k] == *letter){
                dashes[k]= *letter;
                ++match;
            }
        }
        printf("%s\n", dashes);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i need the dashes to be intialized to display only "-" so I enter a string that goes to the tab variable. eg i enter the world foobar the variable tab will be foobar. the variable dashes would display "-----" then i enter a letter if the letter matches one of the characters in variable tab i replace it on the variable dashes. eg i enter o then the variable dashes becomes -oo--.

Comment: @danidar initialize `dashes` by `memset`.

Comment: I did this to initialize the string to - : 
`for (k=0;k<ret;k++){
        dashes[k]='-';
    }` 
then the loop will be replacing the dashes by the real characters when they are found..

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%s", &letter);`

The problem is that, you are asking for a string, passing it to an adress. You either want to do

`scanf("%c", &letter);`or change it to a `int getchar( void );`.

*Edit #1:*

I'd recommend against using `int scanf (const char * format, ...);`. For more information you can read here
[Disadvantages of scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf).

*Edit #2:*

`scanf("%s", letter);` is technically possible, however, as you are only asking for one letter it is wrong to do so. Also remember that strings ends with `\0` so make sure you reserve room for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to your `ret` variable.
 
If you haven't initialized it, the value will be undefined and you won't know if the loop condition will be *true*.

Answer (score 0):

Use %c instead of %s.

%s is get the string up to the white space character. So this is the reason it asking the
ten character from the user.